# Difference between Animation Tween and Animation Controlller

Tags: animation, dart, flutter, widget, flutter-animation

In some Flutter animation tutorials, some uses a `Tween` and an `Animation` object. Some uses `AnimationController` only. Both code below seems to output the same result. So when do we use a Tween with animation and when do we use AnimationController only?

With Tween and animation

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() {
    return _State();
  }
}

class _State extends State<Test> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _animation;
   bool faded = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = new AnimationController(
        value:0.0,
        vsync: this,
        upperBound: 1.0,
        lowerBound: 0.0,
      duration: new Duration(seconds:1),
    );
    _animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        elevation: 0.5,
        title: new Text(
          "Testing views",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
        ),
      ),
      body: _buildBodyAnimationTest(),
//      body:  _buildTuto(),
    );
  }
  Widget _buildBodyAnimationTest(){
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animation, //here is the difference
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          if(faded){
            faded = false;
            _animationController.reverse();
          }else{
            faded = true;
            _animationController.forward();
          }
        },
        child: new Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Without Tween and Animation

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() {
    return _State();
  }
}

class _State extends State<Test> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
   bool faded = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = new AnimationController(
        value:0.0,
        vsync: this,
        upperBound: 1.0,
        lowerBound: 0.0,
      duration: new Duration(seconds:1),
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        elevation: 0.5,
        title: new Text(
          "Testing views",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
        ),
      ),
      body: _buildBodyAnimationTest(),
//      body:  _buildTuto(),
    );
  }
  Widget _buildBodyAnimationTest(){
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animationController, //here is the difference
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          if(faded){
            faded = false;
            _animationController.reverse();
          }else{
            faded = true;
            _animationController.forward();
          }
        },
        child: new Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Tweens are objects used to transform the output of an Animation (such as `AnimationController`).

With `AnimationController`, you typically have a 0-1 floating value. But you rarely want that. 
Tweens allows to map that 0-1 to something more concrete such as red to blue, left to right, ...

Comment: `_animationController = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      lowerBound: 0.0,
      value: 20.0,
      upperBound: 500.0,
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    _animationController.animateTo(300.0);` I have seen that we can have values beyond 0-1 with animationController

Comment: Yeah but tweens can map to values others than double.

Answer (score 2):

Background is my tween sequence color.

```
Animatable<Color> background = TweenSequence<Color>(
      [
        TweenSequenceItem(
          weight: 1.0,
          tween: ColorTween(
            begin: colors[_Substance.dayEndBackground],
            end: colors[_Substance.dayStartBackground],
          ),
        ),
        TweenSequenceItem(
          weight: 1.0,
          tween: ColorTween(
            begin: colors[_Substance.dayStartBackground],
            end: colors[_Substance.dayEndBackground],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

This is my controller defined in `initState()` and updated in every one second:

```
bgUpdateController = AnimationController(
      value: _currentDateTime.hour / 24,
      upperBound: 1,
      lowerBound: 0,
      duration: const Duration(hours: 24),
      vsync: this,
    )..repeat();
```

I have used the above background and controller as `AnimatedBuilder` like below:

```
AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: bgUpdateController,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: background
              .chain(
                CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOutCirc),
              )
              .evaluate(
                AlwaysStoppedAnimation(bgUpdateController.value),
              ),
              ...
```

and the result of my code is:

[image: clock demo]

**Conclusion**

**AnimationController** is for how long the animation would be and how to control from time, upper and lower boundary, how to control data with time, length, sequence, etc. while **AnimationTween** is for the range of animation with time, colour, range, sequence, etc as long the animation would be while.